# Select attributes with numeric labels

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, eav, attribute-options

I believe this is a core Magento bug, but thought I'd come here to ask for some suggestions anyway.

I've got an attribute, let's call it `colour_code`. It's a select attribute (backend is `int`) and it's configurable. It's identical in `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` configuration to the default `size` attribute by the way.

I've been fixturing products with this attribute in some unit tests, and noticed that if my attribute value (label) is numeric, Magento can get confused with the value and the label, for example:

```
# Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract::getAllOptions()
Array
(
    Array
    (
        [value] => 902
        [label] => 143
    )
    Array
    (
        [value] => 386
        [label] => 902
    )
    Array
    (
        [value] => 316
        [label] => A01
    )
)
```

Using the above as a very small example of the result of `getAllOptions` for the attribute's source (`$attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions()`), I check the 
fixtured products values like so:

```
// Product fixture has colour_code: A01
$product->getColourCode(); // 316 <--- the option_id

// Product fixture has colour_code: 902
$product->getColourCode(); // 902 <--- the VALUE
```

**The problem** is when using colour code 902 it returns 902, instead of the option ID. I don't particularly like the fact that Magento returns the option ID, but understand why. That's fine, as long as it's consistent - in this case it's not at all.

Using `902` as the `$value`, I've drilled this down to the logic in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract::getOptionId` line 98, where `strcasecmp($option['label'], $value)==0` returns false, then `$option['value'] == $value` returns true on the first entry in that example array (value = 902, label = 143). In this case, the method returns `$option['value']`, which is 902. It doesn't get a chance to look at the valid option (option_id 386).

```
public function getOptionId($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if (strcasecmp($option['label'], $value)==0 || $option['value'] == $value) {
                                                        ^--- this causes the problem!
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-select attributes, this is expected behaviour.

If you want the frontend/text value of the attribute you can use [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getAttributeText`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1375-L1387) with the attribute code:

```
$product->getAttributeText('colour_code'); // A01
```